# AmpersandJs: Render sub-view

Tags: forms, subview, ampersand.js

getting into AmpersandJs, and having a big showstopper by not figuring out why my sub-view-form isn't rendering it's markup.

My `MainView.render`, works as should:

```
render: function() {
  BaseView.prototype.render.apply(this, arguments);
  this.collectionView = this.renderCollection(this.collection, HSEventView, '.item-container');

  this.renderSubview(new HSEventEditView({
    action: 'create'
  }), '.create-event');

  return this;
},
```

Next, my `SubView.render` (HSEventEditView):

```
render: function () {
  this.renderWithTemplate();

  this.form = new EditForm({
    el: this.query('.edit-form'),
    submitCallback: function (data) {
      debug('submit', data);
    }
  });

  this.registerSubview(this.form);
  debug('render.form.el', this.form.el)
}
```

And finally my `FormView`:

```
module.exports = FormView.extend({
  initialize: function() {
    debug('initialize', this.el)
  },

  autoRender: true,

  fields: function () {
    debug('fields!')


    var fields = [
      new InputView({
        label: 'Name',
        name: 'name',
        value: utils.getDotted(this, 'model.name'),
        placeholder: 'Name',
        parent: this
      })
    ];

    debug('fields', fields)
  }
});
```

The MainView and SubView renders fine, but the 'div.edit-form' DOM-node, where the form markup should be, is empty.

I have tried all variations of including a subview I could dig up, but obviously I am blind to something.

Thanks!

PS! Here is the rendered markup:

```
<section class="page">
  <h2>Events collection</h2>
  <hr>
  <div class="tools">(Tools comming...)</div>
  <hr>
  <div class="item-container events">
    <div class="item event">
      <h3>Event: <span data-hook="name">Event 1</span></h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div class="create-event">
    <div class="item event">
      <h3>Create event: <span data-hook="name"></span></h3>        
      <div class="edit-form"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `fields` is a function, you need to return the fields. In your `Formview`:

```
fields: function () {
  debug('fields!')


  var fields = [
    new InputView({
      label: 'Name',
      name: 'name',
      value: this.model.name,
      placeholder: 'Name',
      parent: this
    })
  ];

  debug('fields', fields)

  // need to return the fields you've declared
  return fields;
}
```

Comment: Yes,  indeed. I copied the code from in the middle of editing,  so I had this fixed, but I'll accept your answer. The main problem is explained here: https://github.com/AmpersandJS/ampersand-form-view/issues/49